# Single Point vs. 5 Point Calibration in HPLC

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, chromatography

Single-Point calibrations aren't that useful for quantitative analysis and there is more room for error in result readings as compared to a 5-Point calibration. Is this why a 5-Point calibration is done instead?

If so, is a more accurate reading the only pro to doing a 5-Point calibration over single point? Anyone with any knowledge on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't regress with a single point, for starters. A calibration curve that encompasses a range of concentrations that are expected for a given analyte will be much more useful that one which is not defined in the response range. There's also the issue of linear and non-linear responses for different concentration ranges (as well as detector response, such as conductivity vs. UV-Vis, for instance).

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything makes sense, but can you elaborate on what you mean by "regress"?

Comment: Here seems to be a good paper on the topic. https://www.webdepot.umontreal.ca/Usagers/sauves/MonDepotPublic/CHM%203103/LCGC%20Eur%20Burke%202001%20-%202%20de%204.pdf // The point about regression is this. How many lines can you draw through a single point? Especially when doing some sort of instrumental analysis you don't want to extrapolate outside the bounds for which you have created a calibration curve. So if I calibrate between 3 and 50 units of something it would be huge mistake to use that calibration to measure something at 230 units. Also most detectors have some sort of background.

Answer (score 0):

So my English is not perfect, however the goal of having a linear regression curve is to estimate the relationship between concentration response and determine the degree of agreement between the increases in concentration and the response, if for example, a certain wavelength has been experimentally demonstrated that the response of the detectors is directly proportional to the concentration This is that it has a slope of 1 and that the correlation coefficient is 1, this means that throughout this concentration interval the answer and concentration will always have the same increase, so that it will not matter that the sample response is higher or low that the one of the so-called calibration point. 
The behavior will always be the same, so the uncertainty of a curve with more than one point or use the factor-response technique will always be despicable, so itself depends on the behavior of the analyte for that exists there are so many methods AOAC that do not need a calibration curve with more than one point and are valid internationally, example: Vitamin A